# disk "Other volume in container"

Tags: macos, mac, catalina

After I erase the mac and reinstall Catalina, this problem came out. I have used few methods I found online:

1. login another user
2. Turn off content caching for "Cache iCloud content"
3. Clean cashes

But none of them worked.

### Does anyone has same issue here and can give some advice? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Deleted an APFS Volume, but it still shows as “Other Volumes” claimed space within the container](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358837/deleted-an-apfs-volume-but-it-still-shows-as-other-volumes-claimed-space-with?rq=1) you should start looking in this direction.